# about volatile and const embellishments

Tags: c++

I find a intersting question about c++
code：

```
volatile const int a = 10;
int *p = const_cast<int*>(&a);
*p = 2;
cout << "value a="<< a << endl;
cout << "value *p=" <<*p << endl;
cout << "address a=" <<&a << endl;  //output 1！！
cout << "address p=" <<p << endl;
```

who can tell me why address of a is 1?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. What did you expect `*p = 2;` to do?

Comment: Since `p` isn't properly qualified (those aren't mere embellishments, they have substantial semantic meaning), your code has undefined behavior. It's pointless to reason about it.

Comment: Surprised there's no compiler warning with volatile const.  "Any process could change the value of this variable, I promise it won't change"...

Comment: @UKMonkey:  `volatile const` is only really used by embedded systems guys, where something "outside the language" can change the variable.

Comment: Ahh - Didn't realise const meant 'I don't plan to change it' rather than 'this can never be changed'  Learn something new every day!

Comment: @UKMonkey it means the object cannot be changed by the program

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

`a` is *originally* declared as `const`.

You attempt to change its value via a pointer that has had the `const`-ness cast away. The language does not allow that.

The `volatile` is a red-herring in this case.